# How to inherit styles of an element from another file in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a navigation bar on the home page with `background-color: white;` On moving to another page. I want it to turn `black`.

My Navigation Styles file:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Nav = styled.nav`
 background-color: #fff;
`
```

My Navigation file where I am importing the styles:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Nav from './NavStyles'

const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <Nav>     
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/shop">Shop</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/cart">Cart</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

My ShopStyles file (where changing the background-color):

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import  { Nav } from '../Nav/NavStyles'

const ShopNav = styled(Nav)`
    background-color: #323232;
`;

export default ShopNav
```

My Shop file:

```
import ShopNav from './ShopStyles'
import { Nav } from '../Nav/NavStyles'

const Shop = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Nav>
               <ShopNav></ShopNav>
            </Nav>
            
            <h1>Over here my shop design will come</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import NavBar from './components/Nav/Nav'
import Shop from './components/Shop/Shop'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"> <Home /> </Route>
        <Route exact path='/shop'> <Shop /> </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do I get the color black with my navigation bar?

Comment: Have you tried this `import  { Nav } from './NavStyles'` ?

Comment: tried in which file? @HassanImam

Comment: I did import in ShopStyles file. Where I am changing my color @HassanImam

Comment: Try to replace `import Nav from './NavStyles'` in your navigation file with the statement which I shared.

Comment: yup tried it not working, @HassanImam

Comment: I believe it's something related to the contents of the navigation file. Like how do I use my NavBar component into the Shop with my additional styling.

Comment: Is `ShopNav` style working in `Shop` component?

Comment: @HassanImam With the code, I wrote? No

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227867/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-zaid-khan).

Comment: Hi, did you get time to look into my issue? @HassanImam

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand about your worry.
The code which you've written is correct and I have also tested your code.
I recommend that you will check your code again.

Comment: I restarted my development server as well but styles still not applied. What I am trying to achieve is that I want to change the background color of my navbar. My Navbar color is white on the homepage but when going to the Shop page I want it to turn black.